# How to show that if $p(A) = 0 \implies p(\lambda_0)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $V \ne \{ 0 \}, A\in L(V), \lambda_0 \in \sigma(A)$. If $p(\lambda)$ is an arbitrary polynomial for which the following applies: $p(A) = 0  $,  prove that $p(\lambda_0)=0$

$L(V)$ = The set of all linear mappings (linear operators) from V to V
$\lambda_0$ = eigenvalue
$\sigma(A)$ = spectrum of A

If I am correct this would involve the Hamilton-Cayley theorem but I don't know how to apply it. I know that $\lambda_0$ is a zero of the polynomial $det(A-\lambda I)$ but I don't even know where to start.

**Edit (hint from mrf):**

Since $V$ is finite, we can mark the degree of the polynomial with n $\implies p(\lambda) = \alpha_n\lambda^n + \alpha_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + ...  +  \alpha_2\lambda^2  + \alpha_1\lambda + \alpha_0$
So $p(A) = \alpha_nA^n + \alpha_{n-1}A^{n-1} + ... + \alpha_2A^2 + \alpha_1A + \alpha_0I$

Let $v$ be an corresponding eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda_0 \implies Av = \lambda_0v$

$p(A)v = (\alpha_nA^n + \alpha_{n-1}A^{n-1} + ... + \alpha_2A^2 + \alpha_1A + \alpha_0I)v $
$p(A)v = \alpha_nA^nv + \alpha_{n-1}A^{n-1}v + ... + \alpha_2A^2v + \alpha_1Av + \alpha_0Iv$

If $\lambda \in \sigma(A) \implies \lambda^k \in \sigma(A^k)$

Proof:
$\lambda \in \sigma(A) \implies \exists v \in V$ so that $Av = \lambda v$
$Av = \lambda v \hspace{10px}| A$
$A^2v = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) =$ A is linear $ =\lambda(Av) = \lambda^2v$
$A^2v = \lambda^2v \hspace{10px}| A$
$A^3v = A(A^2v) = A(\lambda^2 v) =$ A is linear $ =\lambda^2(Av) = \lambda^3v$

And by induction we get: $A^kv = \lambda^k v$

$\implies$

$p(A)v = \alpha_n\lambda_0^nv + \alpha_{n-1}\lambda_0^{n-1}v + ... + \alpha_2\lambda_0^2v + \alpha_1\lambda_0v + \alpha_0v \hspace{10px}| :v$

$p(A) = \alpha_n\lambda_0^n + \alpha_{n-1}\lambda_0^{n-1} + ... + \alpha_2\lambda_0^2 + \alpha_1\lambda_0 + \alpha_0$

$0 = \alpha_n\lambda_0^n + \alpha_{n-1}\lambda_0^{n-1} + ... + \alpha_2\lambda_0^2 + \alpha_1\lambda_0 + \alpha_0$

Comment: @doraemonpaul: What was the point of removing linear-algebra as a tag? matrix-equations is a weird tag anyway with only about 30 questions.

Comment: Agreed. They both apply in this case.

Comment: You don't need the Cayley-Hamilton theorem; this is completely elementary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Compute $p(A)v$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I updated my post, is it correct or did I conclude something wrong?

Comment: @Shirohige It looks good apart from a few typos (you have some extra $I$'s here and there). Also, the degree of $p$ is not necessarily the dimension of $V$.

Comment: Hmmm, I checked my notes and I see that it is only important that V is finite but if we, for example, observe $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ matrices, then the actual dimension of the polynomial would be $n^2$ if I am correct so I don't need to specify the dimension of V but may I ask where do I have the extra $I's$ ? We defined $A^0 = I$ so that $\alpha_0x^0=\alpha_0\lambda^0=\alpha_0A^0=\alpha_0I$

Comment: *degree (not dimension) of the polynomial

Comment: For example, in $0 = \alpha_n\lambda_0^n + \alpha_{n-1}\lambda_0^{n-1} + ... + \alpha_2\lambda_0^2 + \alpha_1\lambda_0 + \alpha_0I$, the final $I$ makes no sense.

Comment: Oh now I get it, I switched from matrices to $\lambda_0$ and forgot to remove the $I's$ because of course $I$ is a matrix. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is true in a much more general context.

If you have some (unital) algebra $\mathbf A$ over arbitrary field $\bf K$ (it could be a Banach algebra or finite dimensional, but not necessarily) and some $A\in {\bf A}$ and a polynomial $p\in {\bf K}[X]$ such that $p(A)=0$, then for any $\lambda$ if $p(\lambda)\neq 0$, then $(A-\lambda\cdot{\bf 1})$ is invertible in ${\bf A}$.

To see this, notice that you have $-p(\lambda\cdot {\bf 1})=p(A)-p(\lambda \cdot {\bf 1})=(A-\lambda\cdot {\bf 1})g(A)$ for some polynomial $g\in {\bf K}[X]$. In particular ${\bf 1}=(A-\lambda\cdot {\bf 1})(-p(\lambda)^{-1}g(A))$.

In fact, we could replace ${\bf K}$ with some arbitrary (commutative unital) ring if we require that $p(\lambda)$ be invertible and not just nonzero.

Comment: I wonder, why did someone downvote this answer?

Comment: Just to let you know, I am the one who voted it UP. It seems that some people think that "not liking generalizations" is a good reason to down vote a good answer. :/

Comment: @Shirohige: Thanks, it's good to know. :)