# If $A^2+2A+I_n=O_n$ then $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a matrix of $n\times n$ and $I_n, O_n$ the identity and nule matrix respectively. How to prove that if $A^2+2A+I_n=O_n$ then $A$ is invertible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $A(A+2I_n)=-I_n$.

More generally, you can prove in the same way that if $P(A)=0$ for some polynomial $P$ satisfying $P(0) \neq 0$, then $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Seirios if $A(A+2I_n)=-I_n$ then $|A||A+2I_n|=(-1)^n$ but as prove that $|A|\neq 0$?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero : $$A(A+2I)=-I\implies A\cdot(-(A+2I)) = I\ldots$$ Also, $$|A|=0\implies |A|\,|A+2I|=0\neq(-1)^n\ldots$$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392859/how-to-show-that-if-pa-0-implies-p-lambda-0-0/393001#393001

Comment: More generally, over an arbitrary commutative ring $R$, the condition is $P(0)$ is invertible in $R$.

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is not invertible then $\exists\ x\ne 0$ such that $Ax=0$ Then note that $A^2+2A+I=0\Rightarrow\ x=0$ which is a contradiction. Hence $A$ must be invertible.

In general, it follows from the argument that, if $P(A)=0$ for some polynomial $P$ such that $P(0)\ne 0$ then $A$ must be invertible.

Answer (score 3):

This is Miscellaneous Exercise 1.29 in [Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) on p 125. All solutions are [here](https://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780199654444/studentsolutions/).

[image]

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! I converted your image link to an image, but it is not enough. Screenshots are disliked here (with a good reason). Use text copy-paste instead. I have no hearth to vote your answer for deletion, but it will likely happen. :-( (We have also Latex fomatting, write `$A^n$` and you will get $A^n$).

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$A^2+2A+I=0\implies -A(A+2I)=I\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is a power of $(x+1)$, and hence its characteristic polynomial is $(x+1)^n$. This polynomial has constant term $=1$. This term is equal to $(-1)^n\det A$, when we require that the characteristic polynomial should be monic. Hence the determinant of $A$ is always $\not=0$. So...what?

Comment: I'm afraid there's a fair chance this all would sound like chinese to someone asking such an elementary question...It is correct, though (except that the constant term of the char. pol. is the determinant... *up to sign* )

Comment: @DonAntonio I see. But why about the determinant up to a sign? I thought that $\text{char}(A)(x):=\det(A-xI)$, so that $\text{constant term}=\text{char}(A)(0)=\det(A)$?

Comment: the definition I work with is $\,char(A)=\det(xI-A)\,$ , in order to **always** get a monic polyomial (i.e., with greatest coefficients always equal to $\,+1\,$)

Comment: @DonAntonio I have edited to take into account that definition.

Comment: Nice @awllower, but then you don't need that "or..." part there: it's enough to point that the free coefficient is $\,(-1)^n\det A\;$

Answer (score 0):

Think about $B=-A-2I$, and prove that $AB=BA=I$.

Comment: This argument is already on the more than once.

Comment: Sorry, I'm the new one to this website and didn't notice that argument has been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

since $(A+I)^2=0$ we have $A+I$ nilpotent, hence $I-(I+A) = -A$ is invertible.