# Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $A^2+A+I_n =0_n$. Prove that $A^3=I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $A^2+A+I_n =0_n$. Prove that $A^3=I_n$.

*Progress*:
I managed to prove that $A$ is invertible. Checked out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444831/if-a22ai-n-o-n-then-a-is-invertible), with no help yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

remember:

$$
A^3-I=(A-I)(A^2+A+I)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Times by $A$ to get $$A^3 + A^2 + A = 0$$ so $$A^3 = -A^2 - A$$ But we know from the given condition that $I_n = - A^2 - A$, so $A^3 = I_n$.

This is quite a typical trick used in the application of what is known as the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

$$A^2+A+I=0\Rightarrow A^2+A=-I$$
Therefore 
$$A(A^2+A+I)=A\cdot 0=0\Rightarrow A^3+A^2+A=0\Rightarrow A^3+(-I)=0\Rightarrow A^3=I$$

Comment: what can we say about the eigen values of A, ? are they real always or imaginary?

Comment: Well let $\lambda\neq 0$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ then $Ax=\lambda x$ implies $A^3x=\lambda^3 x$ which together with the equation $A^3=I$ yields $\lambda^3 x=x$. Therefore any nontrivial eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $\lambda^3=1$. The three roots of unity, two of which are complex numbers.